# Not able to redirect to other page in PHP after running KSH

Tags: php, ksh

I am having below code present in a PHP file.

```
    exec("run_gen_execute_map.ksh &");

    header("location:cycle_task_actions.php);
```

I am not able to redirect to cycle_task_actions.php after executing the KSH file. Could someone please help me out on this.

Comment: You're missing " at the end of your header string.

Answer (score 1):

1. Missing " 2nd line
2. **location:cycle_task_actions.php** should be **Location:cycle_task_actions.php**

   ```
   exec("run_gen_execute_map.ksh &");

   header("Location:cycle_task_actions.php");
   ```

Comment: It doesn't matter if 'L' in location is lowercase or not.

Comment: The convention seems to lean that it's uppercase though.

Comment: Its still not working even after trying the above changes

Comment: I tried the code as

`exec("/usr/bin/nohup run_gen_execute_map.ksh &");`

Its working fine now